# How to set a delay between scripts?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, delay

First off, I know that there are many other questions that ask this question, but I looked through the answers and they are too complicated for me. I just started learning this and I am seeking an answer to my specific needs, thanks!

I want to make a script that will open a link every second or two.
How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `setTimeout()`(only executes once) and `setInterval`(repeats). It's not too hard to use.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/T8zV3/) here. You may like to change the function body to fit your needs.

[W3Schools setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

[W3Schools setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Answer (score 0):

There is a setTimeout function in javascript that will execute a script after a specified timeout.

http://javascript.info/tutorial/settimeout-setinterval

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) or [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout)

```
function link() {
    window.open('_blank');
}
var i = setInterval(link,1000);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tUY4p/)

I'm assuming from your question, 'every second or two', means you may want interval.

*you will have to turn your pop up blocker off for this to work*